# Cannot construct a pair containing a const int and a non-copyable (but moveable) object in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class, which I will refer to as NonCopyable, which cannot be copied, but can be moved (both move constructed and move assigned). I am trying to construct a `std::pair<const int, NonCopyable>`, but the line below will not compile.

```
std::pair<const int, NonCopyable>(1, NonCopyable());
```

The error I receive is:

```
no matching function for call to 'std::pair<const int, NonCopyable>::pair(int, NonCopyable)'
```

Why does the line fail to compile? Since NonCopyable is move constructible/assignable, I would expect it to use the constructor `template<class U1, class U2> constexpr pair(U1&& x, U2&& y)`.

Edit:

So I left out some information that I did not think was relevant, but in fact was and is very important.

I have a class ContainsNC, which contains a non-copyable class NonCopyable. I am trying to construct a `std::pair<const int, ContainsNC>`, but the code below fails to compile.

```
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
struct NonCopyable {
    NonCopyable() = default;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable&&) = default;
    NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(NonCopyable&&) = default;
};

class ContainsNC {
    public:
        ~ContainsNC() {
            std::cout << "destruct" << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        NonCopyable nc;
};

int main() {
    std::pair<const int, ContainsNC>(1, ContainsNC());
}
```

Now, if the custom destructor of ContainsNC is commented out, the code compiles. Why does the custom destructor affect construction of the `std::pair<const int, ContainsNC>`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error described. See [coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/922e8a8d0e3718d5). Please provide an minimal self-contained example that can be used to reproduce the error, and state compiler version and compiler flags.

Comment: @Brian: I get a similar error when making the class non-copyable using `NonCopyable(NonCopyable&) = delete;` Adding a `const` avoids the error. Of course, it would help if the question did contain the relevant detail, i.e., how `NonCopyable` is declared, already.

Comment: While working on a self-contained example, I found that some things left out of the original post were important, so I am working on providing a better example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rule which says `When destructor is defined, move operations are deleted and they are not generated by compiler default.`

So you have to add move constructor to your class.

```
class ContainsNC {
    public:
        ~ContainsNC() {
            std::cout << "destruct" << std::endl;
        }

        ContainsNC(ContainsNC&&) = default;
    private:
        NonCopyable nc;
};
```

After adding move ctor, default constructor is deleted, you have to provide it too to compile your code:

```
class ContainsNC {
    public:
        ~ContainsNC() {
            std::cout << "destruct" << std::endl;
        }
        ContainsNC() = default;
        ContainsNC(ContainsNC&&) = default;
    private:
        NonCopyable nc;
};
```

You can check [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) to see when move operations are generated for class default by compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the help. That was the cause of my problem.